# Random Int from strings

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on something and this won't work, can you help?

```
num1 = int(code1)
num2 = int(code2)
rnd = randint(num1, num2)
print(rnd)
```

ERROR:
I imported the randint from random!

```
ERRIR: in randint return self.randrange(a, b+1)
```

Comment: What is the actual stacktrace?

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: Im converting a string to int then I'm doing a random but it wont work

Comment: There's 2 string that i converted then im using randint(num1, num2) but it won't work

Comment: What are the values of num1 and num2? My feeling is that num2 is smaller than num1

Comment: I found out, i typed something wrong in the code before that thx for quick responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you call `randint(10,5)` you will get error. You get this error when first argument is more than the second argument in `randint()` method. If you just want to get a random number between num1 and num2 you can resolve this error by a small trick

```
num1 = int(code1)
num2 = int(code2)
rnd = randint(min(num1,num2), max(num1,num2))
print(rnd)
```